# How can I run a command on a remote machine with Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm using following code to connect to a remote machine and try to execute one simple command on remote machine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Telnet;

$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>2, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('172.168.12.58');
$telnet->waitfor('/login:\s*/');
$telnet->print('admin');
$telnet->waitfor('/password:\s*/');
$telnet->print('Blue');

#$telnet->cmd('ver > C:\\log.txt');
$telnet->cmd('mkdir gy');
```

But when I'm executing this script it is throwing error messages

```
[root@localhost]# perl tt.pl
command timed-out at tt.pl line 12
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you have commented out `use strict;`?

Answer (score 5):

From your code it seems that you have *nix. Use of perl module [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm) make it more easy

Sample Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Net::SSH::Perl
my $cmd = 'command';
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("hostname", debug=>0);
$ssh->login("username","password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
print $stdout;
```

And sample code for Net::Telnet

```
use Net::Telnet ();
    my $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10,
                          Prompt => '/bash\$ $/');
    $t->open("sparky");
    $t->login($username, $passwd);
    my @lines = $t->cmd("who");
    print @lines;
```

You can look at more example for [Net Telnet Examples](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm#EXAMPLES)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to provide a "prompt" constructor parameter - see [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=703974)

The example they gave:

```
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet (
    Timeout=>10, 
    Prompt=>'/Bilbo>$/i',   #### <<<==============
    Errmode=>'die', 
    Dump_Log=>'dump.txt', 
    Input_log=>'input.txt', 
    Output_log=>'output.txt', 
);
```